# Why Jenkins isn't able to start the service, but it is starting fine when I start it manually?

Tags: shell, tomcat, jenkins, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to start HYBRIS server from Jenkins.

When I run the `sh hybrisserver.sh` start command manually in the server it starts correctly.

But, when I try to run the same command through Jenkins it is not able to start the service.

The Hybris server and Jenkins master are connected through a slave (node).

What could be the issue?

Comment: Maybe your user "jenkins" or whatever you use for jenkins have no right to execute this. (the X in an ls -l ).
Did you run it manually with the same user ?

Comment: Yes I am using the same user, both manually and from Jenkins.

Comment: @M.Be: You don't need x-rights on *hybrisserver.sh*  if you start it in the way the OP did.

Comment: There are really no error messages in the Jenkins console output???? What output do you get when you run it with `sh -x hybrisserver.sh`?

Comment: @ANILMAHAPATRAOfficial when you say it's not starting, have you got an error? Or just nothing happened? Maybe you can use `$?` to know the status

Comment: The Jenkins console doesn't show much. It says the server started. The log for this gets stored in a console-date.log file. It says "Wrapper Stopped" and gets stuck there. maybe some JVM heap memory issue. How can I pass memory arguments to the agent in a correct way? I tried -Xmx2G in node configuration of Jenkins but it did nothing.

Comment: @M.Be this is the error: INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/12/19 12:10:36.103 |
ERROR  | wrapper  | main    | 2016/12/19 12:10:36.103 | JVM did not exit on request, termination requested.
STATUS | wrapper  | main    | 2016/12/19 12:10:36.212 | JVM received a signal SIGKILL (9).
STATUS | wrapper  | main    | 2016/12/19 12:10:36.212 | JVM process is gone.
STATUS | wrapper  | main    | 2016/12/19 12:10:36.212 | JVM exited after being requested to terminate.
STATUS | wrapper  | main    | 2016/12/19 12:10:36.512 | <-- Wrapper Stopped

Comment: When you start a service, you should run it as background process, otherwise when the job finishes it will terminate your service. So amend your job to make the service as sh hybrisserver.sh &

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include following line of entry on jenkins job and it will start nicely.

```html
export CATALINA_BASE="<Your Hybris DIR>/hybris/bin/platform/tomcat"
export WRAPPER_CONF="$CATALINA_BASE/conf/wrapper.conf"
sudo sh <Your Hybris DIR>/hybris/bin/platform/tomcat/bin/wrapper.sh start
```

Answer (score 0):

try setting up tools environment 
using https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Tool+Environment+Plugin 
then set up required env variable and run slave as cmd through admin rights